# Previous realm data is lost when Realm migration is done in android

Tags: android, realm

Previously I was using 0.82.0 realm version and now I am using 0.87.0 version.According to project requirements i am attempting to add two new tables to existing realm schema.

For that I added below code..

```
public class UnitDetails extends RealmObject {

    private int unitUid;

    private double noOfrooms;

    private int unitArea;

    private int fId;

    private int fNum;

    private int maxAvailablity;

    // and setters and getter methods

}

public class Quote extends RealmObject {

    private String qName;
    private String qLocation;

    // and setters and getter methods

}
```

and Migration code is as follows,creating a RealmConfiguration instance using appication context, and calling getRealmInstance() method wherever Realm instance is needed.

```
public class RealmUtils  {

    private static RealmConfiguration config;

    public static void createRealmConfig(Context context) { 

        config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(context)
                .name("default.realm1")
                .schemaVersion(1)
                .migration(new CustomMigration())
                .build();
    }

    public static Realm getRealmInstance() { 

        return Realm.getInstance(config);
    }
}

public class CustomMigration implements RealmMigration {

    @Override
    public void migrate(final DynamicRealm realm, long oldVersion, long newVersion) {
        RealmSchema schema = realm.getSchema();
        if (oldVersion == 0) {
            RealmObjectSchema quoteSchema = schema.create("Quote")
                    .addField("qName", String.class)
                    .addField("qLocation", String.class);

            RealmObjectSchema unitDetailsSchema = schema.create("UnitDetails")
                    .addField("unitUid", int.class)
                    .addField("noOfrooms", double.class)
                    .addField("unitArea", int.class)
                    .addField("fId", int.class)
                    .addField("fNum", int.class)
                    .addField("maxAvailablity", int.class);
            oldVersion++;
        }
    }
}
```

When I update my app by installing new apk, I am not getting RealmMigrationNeededException but previous data is lost.

what is going wrong here and how to prevent data loss? Do I need to do anything with existing tables? What all I should take care of, as I am using new realm version ?

Comment: The above code should work, and shouldn't result in any loss of data. Is the name of the Realm really `default.realm1`?

Comment: for shema version zero it was default.realm and I have given default.realm1 name for version one.

Comment: That is why your data is gone. The name is also the name of the file used. If you change that name you create a completely new file.

Answer (score 3):

You should not update the name as well, just the version number. The following configuration should work:

```
public class RealmUtils  {

    private static RealmConfiguration config;

    public static void createRealmConfig(Context context) { 

        config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(context)                                           
                .schemaVersion(1)
                .migration(new CustomMigration())
                .build();
    }

    public static Realm getRealmInstance() { 

        return Realm.getInstance(config);
    }
}
```

Comment: Now i am getting exception

Comment: Error io.realm.exceptions.RealmMigrationNeededException: Field 'slug' is required. Either set @Required to field 'slug' or migrate using io.realm.internal.Table.convertColumnToNullable().
  
private String slug;                                                                                              and In some places getting IllegalArgumentException "A non-null RealmConfiguration must be provided"

Comment: slug is field of existing table here

Comment: That seems unrelated to the code you posted above as there is no field named `slug`. The later is probably because you forgot to call `createRealmConfig` before calling `getRealmInstance`

Comment: Before I did migration everything was fine and slug is field of existing Realm table. It is giving Error io.realm.exceptions.RealmMigrationNeededException:  for every field which is not primitive. and I am calling createRealmConfig() in oncretae of the launcher(first) activity of the app. And i am populating the data from JSON, so some values may come null, how to handle this??  what is equal to convertColumnToNullable() in 0.87.0 version

Comment: `setNullable("field", true)`

Comment: As i said, I just have changed Realm version to 0.87.0. Previously it was 0.82.0 and everything was working fine and no need to add @Required and etc attributes for every non primitive field. Please let me know how to handle field attributes like convertColumnToNullable() and convertColumnToNotNullable() and how to update a field attributes while migration ?

Comment: The reason that is required is that we introduced Null support in 0.83: https://realm.io/news/realm-java-0.83.0/ . In 0.86 we changed the migration API so you can use `realmObjectSchema.setNullable("field", false)` instead of `table.convertColumnToNotNullable()`. See here: https://realm.io/news/realm-java-0.86.0/

Comment: schema.get("Quote")
            .setNullable("fName",false)
            .setNullable("fLocation",false); like this right ?

Comment: Error java.lang.IllegalStateException: Field is already nullable: field1   if i add schema.setNullable("field1",true); in migrate() method and  Error java.lang.IllegalStateException: Field is already required: field2 for schema.setNullable("field2",false). 
and If i don't add setNullable(String field , boolean value) it was giving exception  Error io.realm.exceptions.RealmMigrationNeededException: Field 'field' is required. Either set @Required to field 'name' or migrate using io.realm.internal.Table.convertColumnToNullable().

Comment: what could be the reason ?? and Should I call createRealmConfig() each time i call getRealmInstance() ??

Comment: No that shouldn't be needed. You can use `setDefaultInstance` in the Application onCreate and then use `getDefaultInstance` instead.

Comment: Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(new RealmConfiguration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .schemaVersion(1)
                .migration(new MyMigration())
                .build());
    
and  Realm.getDefaultInstance() right ??   and please help me with 3rd question from bottom(Error java.lang.IllegalStateException:.............)

Comment: You are getting an IllegalStateException because the field is already nullable. Setting a field to a state it already has will throw an exception as you really should know the state of your fields before beginning a migration. Otherwise you have a very high risk of creating more bugs. If you want you can use `!isNullable("field")` before setting `setNullable("field", true), but I would encourage you to think about how your model classes are before and after the migration instead.